# Node.js application acting as producer and consumer

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I am now working on the application saving data into the database using the REST API. The basic flow is: REST API -> object -> save to database. I wanted to introduce the queue to the application, having in mind the idea of the producer and consumer being a part of one, abovementioned application.

Is it possible for the Node.js application to act as both producer and consumer of the queue? Knowing that Node.js is single-threaded language, does it give me any other choice instead of creating two applications - one producing to the queue and the second one - waiting actively for messages in a queue and saving to the database?

Also, the requirement here would be for an application to process any item that hasn't been acknowledged on the queue on the restart. That also makes me think that the 'two applications' architecture is the best idea here.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Of course two separate application is the best idea here. I am not sure if it is possible to use same application as producer and consumer also I do not see the reason behind doing this.

Comment: Yes, it will work having a single nodejs app acting as consumer and publisher at the same time. No probs.

Comment: @MartinWickman, could you provide some examples on how to achieve this? I mean, for an application to act as a regular express.js application accepting various requests, but also being able to recover when restarted and there's N messages in the queue? Preferably handle items from queue using its internal business logic.

I cannot grasp on the concept of one application being responsible for two actions, handling requests but also handling queue async.

Comment: Too many questions there my friend :-) But in short, create a [consumer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html) during application startup. The consumer which listens on the queue (it's an async event). Publishing to rabbit is akin to writing to a database like mysql. Rabbit will resend messages that aren't ack'ed so restarts are usually not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nodejs is able to do that and is well suited for every I/O intensive application use case. The point here is "what are you trying to achieve"? message queues are meant to  make different applications communicate together, while if you need an in-process event bus is a total overkill. There are many easier and efficient ways to propagate messages between decoupled components of the same nodejs app; one of these way is [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) that let your components collaborate in a pubsub fashion

If you are convinced that an AMQP broker is you solution, you just need to

- Define a "producer" class that publishes data on an exchange *myExchange*
- Define a "consumer" queue that declares a queue *myQueue*
- Create a binding at application startup between myExchange and myQueue, based on some routing key. Then, when a message is received from "consumer" you need to **acknowledge** after db saving. When a message is acked, it will be destroyed since it's already been consumed. You can decide, after an error, to recover the message via NACK

There are nodejs libraries that make code easier, such as [Rascal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rascal)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **YES** and **use two separate connections for publishing and consuming**

> Is it possible for the NodeJS application to act as both producer and consumer of the queue?

**I would even state that it is a good usecase matching extremely well with NodeJS philosophy and threading mechanism.**

> Knowing that Node.js is single-threaded language, does it give me any other choice instead of creating two applications - one producing to the queue and the second one - waiting actively for messages in a queue and saving to the database?

You can have one application handling both, just be aware that if your client is publish too fast for the server to handle, RabbitMQ can apply back pressure on the TCP connection, thus consuming on a back-pressured TCP connection would greatly affect consumer performance.